# How to return the first serialized object rather than all in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an API (using django-rest-framework) with two models (e.g. Users and Cars).

I'm trying to get the user's latest (highest ID) Car also returned when the User is queried.

I've tried including `cars = CarSerializer(many=True)` in the User serializer, which returns all cars for that user.

I've tried `cars = CarSerializer(many=False)`, which returns the format I want, but no cars turn up.

## Code

*car model*

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='')
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='cars')
```

*car serializer*

```py
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'year', 'owner')
```

*user serializer*

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'car')
```

*car view*

```py
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

*user view*

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

## What I'm looking for

Given two cars belonging to the user with an ID of 1:

```
id: 1
owner: 1
name: "kinda okay car"
year: 2012

id: 2
owner: 1
name: "the fastest one"
year: 2020
```

*JSON Result of GET /users/1*

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "McFastCar",
  "car": {
    "name": "the fastest one",
    "year": 2020
  }
}
```

## What I currently get

*JSON Result of GET /users/1*

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "McFastCar",
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "owner": 1
      "name": "the fastest one",
      "year": 2020
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "owner": 1
      "name": "kinda okay car",
      "year": 2012
    }
  ],
}
```

Thanks, I wheely hope you can help drive me towards a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually create a `@property` in your `User` model that returns the last car only:

```py
class User:
    ...

    @property
    def last_car(self):
        return self.cars.last()
```

And then in the `UserSerializer` you can just serialize this property:

```py
class UserSerializer:
    last_car = CarSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (..., 'last_car')
```

This would do the trick.

---

*P.S.* : If you still want your latest car entry to be serialized as `"car": { ... }` but not `"last_car": { ... }` , you can use [the `source` attribute](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) on the `CarSerializer` itself:

```
class UserSerializer:
    car = CarSerializer(source='last_car', read_only=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CarSerializer` must be linked with a queryset or an object otherwise it will return all objects

```
# get the car object with the highest using order_by
car =  Car.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
# build a car serializer from the car object
car_serializer = CarSerializer(car, many=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you mean, but unfortunately I'm no closer to a solution.

The car queryset is linked in the ViewSet I've edited my question to reflect this.
I think, even if it did work, polling the object this way will also lose the "owner" relationship.

Comment: I've tried this in my django project and it worked fine. `car_serializer.data` will return the json representation of the car object.

Answer (score 0):

You can write UserSerializers like bellow

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cars = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'cars')

    def get_cars(self, instance):
        cars = instance.cars.all().order_by('-year')
        return CarSerializer([cars[0], ], many=True).data
```

and calling `GET /users/1` will return results like this

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Bob",
    "last_name": "McFastCar",
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "the fastest one",
            "year": 2020,
            "owner": 2,
            "first_name": "Bob"
        }
    ]
}
```

The bellow line gave me an unknown error so I've written it with many=True

```
return CarSerializer(cars, many=False).data
```